# Media player is playing well on Google Assistant while Simulator is not

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I implemented **simple Media Player** on AOG by using `MediaResponse`

The Media Player can play correctly both side :

- Actions on Google `simulator`
- `Google Assistant` on Mobile Phone

Then,

While It able to do these features on `Google Assistant` :

- **Play**
- **Pause**
- **Stop**
- **Resume**

`Simulator` can not do this (as the image, it always ask me again)

I wonder why?

People who know, help me explain?

*p/s :*

*And, what is difference between `pause` and `stop`?*

*On Google Assistant, I saw that they have same feature, it means `stop` totally similar with `pause`.*

[image]

[image]

**MediaPlayerUtils.js**

```
// Library
const {
MediaObject,
MediaResponse,
SimpleResponse,
Suggestions
} = require('actions-on-google');

class MediaPlayerUtils {

getMediaResponse(song) {
    // This object used to play Media on Google Home
    var mediaResponse = new MediaResponse();
    mediaResponse.mediaType = "AUDIO";

    var mediaObject = new MediaObject({
        url: ""
    });

    mediaObject.name = song.title;
    mediaObject.contentUrl = song.url;

    mediaResponse.mediaObjects = [];
    mediaResponse.mediaObjects.push(mediaObject);

    var Media = require('../model/data/Media');

    // Media Response : Play audio
    return new Media(song, mediaResponse);
}

playSong(conv, song) {
    var media = require('../model/data/Media');
    media = this.getMediaResponse(song);

    console.log("playSong() " + song.title + " " + song.url);

    // Media Response : Play audio
    conv.ask(new SimpleResponse(" ")); // Able to set song title before playing song in here
    conv.ask(media.mediaResponse);
    conv.ask(new Suggestions(
        "next",
        "back",
        "previous",
        "play",
        "pause",
        "resume",
        "stop"));
    conv.ask(new SimpleResponse(""));
};

}

module.exports = MediaPlayerUtils;
```

**routes.js**

```
'use strict';


const {
dialogflow
} = require('actions-on-google');

const assistant = dialogflow({ debug: true });

const MediaPlayerUtils = require('./util/MediaPlayerUtils');
const mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayerUtils();

module.exports = function (app) {

assistant.intent('Default Fallback Intent', (conv) => {
    conv.close("Goodbye");
});

assistant.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
    var song = {
        title: "Test",
        url: "https://TEST_URL.mp3"
    };

    console.log("Default Welcome Intent");

    mediaPlayer.playSong(conv, song);
});

module.exports.googleHomeActions = assistant;

app.post('/webhook', assistant);
};
```

**Media.js**

```
var Media = function (song, mediaResponse) {
this.song = song;
this.mediaResponse = mediaResponse;
}

module.exports = Media;
```

Comment: Please file a bug: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Comment: I asked them already. As the Docs said : [Media responses are supported on Android phones and on Google Home](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes is correct.

But currently as Docs said : [Media responses are supported on Android phones and on Google Home](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses)